# ReactJS trying to filter a column in ag grid with a search input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Im trying to create a search input box that filters the genre column in ag grid using reactjs. basically the endpoint of the url has a different endpoint so i cant just query it with =${search} at the end. as the url for genre is http://url/library/books?genre= and i want all books displayed initially if that makes sense. i have absolutely no idea how to do it so any help to push me in the right direction would be appreciated/links to something that will help or anything. currently the following code will give me all information like i want but i just need to add a search input to filter:

```
function App () {
  const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] =useState ("");
  const url = "http://url/library/books";
 const columns = [ 
      {headerName: "Title", field: "title"},
      {headerName: "Author", field: "author"},
      {headerName: "Genre", field: "genre", sortable: true},
  ];

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => json.map(res => {
        return{
        title: res.title,
        author: res.author,
        genre: res.genre,
    };
  })
      ).then(res => setRowData(res));
},[]);

return (
<SearchFilter onSubmit ={setSearch} />
<AgGridReact
        columnDefs={columns}
        rowData={rowData}
        pagination={true}
        paginationPageSize={20}/>
}
```

Comment: the last ".then" doesnt look right. and frankly, i have no idea what you're trying to do. i dont see a input element, don't see a filter-like function. is it about getting data? pls pls pls consider putting together a minimum set of pcs to solve the problem you're having. draw us a picture with words pointing at elements if you have to. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you fetch all books first, there are two ways to go about this.

---

### Fetching all books and filtering locally

As you are fetching all books, you can just filter the local list of books like so:

The books are stored as an array. Currently you're passing them to the `AgGridReact` component like this:

```
<AgGridReact
  rowData={rowData} // books array
  // other props...
}
```

Whatever array you pass to the `rowData` prop, is what will be rendered. To only render a subset of books, you simply pass the subset of books instead of all books, using the array's `filter` function:

```
<AgGridReact
rowData={rowData.filter(b => b.genre === "fantasy")}
  // other props...
}
```

Now only the books with `genre` equal to `fantasy` will be passed to `AgGridReact`.

Obviously you want to use the value of `search` filter key, and not the fixed string "fantasy".

```
rowData={rowData.filter(b => b.genre === search)}
```

But there is a bug here. When the value of `search` is an empty string, only books with an empty genre will be visible, but we want to show all books in this case.

You can correct it by only using the `search` string if there is one:

```
rowData={search ? rowData.filter(b => b.genre === search) : rowData}
```

Now the books will be filtered by genre from user input.

---

### Calling the genre endpoint

To make an API request when the filter changes, you can simply change your `useEffect` to be an effect that runs whenever there is a new filter:

```
// where urlWithgenre === "http://url/library/books?genre="
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`${urlWithGenre}${search}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) =>
      json.map((res) => ({
        title: res.title,
        author: res.author,
        genre: res.genre,
      }))
    )
    .then((res) => setRowData(res))
}, [search]) // Notice that we add search variable to the dependency array
```

As the `search` variable is added to the dependency array, this effect will run whenever the search value changes. This effect will also run once on component mount that will have the result of fetching all books.

There is a bug here, as when `search` is set to an empty string `''`, we want to fetch all books, not books with a specific genre.

You can change the effect like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(search ? `${urlWithGenre}${search}` : url)
  // rest of effect...
```

This will get all books if the search string is empty.

---

Obviously this is not a very efficient way to handle the data.

For example, if you search for `fiction`, then search for `horror`, then search for `fiction` again, we have already gone to the trouble of fetching fiction books, but deleted them when we searched for horror books. It would be a better idea to store everything that we fetch locally, incase the user searches for the same thing more than once.

It may even be better to limit the input to be a dropdown select of all possible genres that the API has, so that you can't search for genres that won't have any results.